# Change activities to fragments

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

For my thesis I'm doing an Android app and its more or less almost done but my problem is that I started it using activities and now I really should swap to fragments and I'd like to change as few as possible. Due to copyrights of such app in my country I can only give some idea how it looks.
I have top header with user info etc which is build on activity, and it should stay like it is, then I have button panel build as activity and then there is content which I need to rewrite to fragments. The base structure of app is build on BaseActivity class and all other classes extend BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends  ActionBarActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // some code here, db connectors etc
    }
// Some more functions like sending session context to server, retriving it
    void setNavigationDrawer() {
        setUserInfo(sessionContext);

        DrawerLayout sDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        sDrawerLayout = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // Set the adapter for the list view
        sDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, DisplayedUserInfo));
        // Set the list's click listener

        sDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                sDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        );

        // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
        sDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(sDrawerToggle);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

     protected void setUpNavigation() {
    // setting nav buttons i.e
    if(userInfo != null) {
            userInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), userInfoActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("SessionContext", sessionContext);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, GET_CURRENT_USER);
                }
            });
        }
     }
}
```

and example activity class which I need to change.

```
public class UserInfoActivity extends BaseActivity {
 // var declarations
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_info_layout);

        setNavigationDrawer();
        setUpNavigation();
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_table);
        loadData();

        Button btnUsrNav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_user);
        btnUsrNav.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nav));
        btnUsrkNav.setEnabled(false);
    }

   // some functions as creating tables etc
}
```

My basic idea is to create BaseFragment class extending Fragment, move here all functions from BaseActivity like setUpNavigation() setNavigationDrawer() (do I need to change anything in them) and then just change all extend BaseActivity to extend BaseFragment but I dont really know how to set up all fragments inside that BaseActivity. But its only idea and I'm not sure if it would work out.

Comment: Please avoid posting links to code, links that eventually can go dead, but instead post the code itself. I've taken the liberty of doing this for you today, but in the future hope that you will do this yourself.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry. Just didnt want to make it too long since I thought of posting more code.

Comment: The key question for me is always -- "how much information and code should I post in my question?" And the answer is always vague, "enough but not too much". Stick around here, ask questions, answer questions, and you'll get a better understanding of what constitutes enough but not too much. As an aside, I know nothing about Android, so that's the extent of help I can give you. Much luck!